# Is the PAL version of Halo 4 playable on an NTSC Xbox 360?

Tags: region-lock, halo-4

I have an NTSC Xbox 360. Can I play a PAL Halo 4 on it?

Answer (score 6):

I can confirm!  I have PAL Halo 4 running on my US NTSC Xbox with no issues!

Answer (score 0):

[Link](https://forums.halowaypoint.com/yaf_postsm1667448_Is-Halo-4-region-free.aspx?find=lastpost#post1667448)

Says it works on his NTSC-J console so hopefully it does.

But I have no concrete evidence yet.